# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user_accounts'

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django and the CSV built in library and calling/referencing the User Model. I get that error on the implementing line in my python(django) code.

```
import csv
from user_accounts.models import CustomUser

with open('test_data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            try:
                user_search = CustomUser.objects.get(
                    id=row["UserId"],
                    username=row["UserName"]
                )
                print('user: ', user_search)

            except:
                print('except returned')
                continue
            print(
                f'\t{row["Id"]} works in the {row["UserId"]} department, '
                f'and was born in {row["UserName"]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Comment: Can you run the script using `python manage.py shell < your_script.py`?

Comment: Importing error check the directory whether you're importing models correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem/error came because its a python script not binded to the Django module. So there's a need to import the module and initialize it before anything else like:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mrc_mis.settings')

import django
django.setup()
```

And also I removed the file outside the project and being the same level with `manage.py`